# Weird action by javascript for onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> Hi! I'm trying to create a carousel/image slider which is automatic and reactable to onclick event but for somereason the onclick event messesup the automatic flow of the slider even though the code makes perfect sens!

Could someone tell me whats wrong in this code and a solution to fix it please! thank you!

```js
var i = 0;    
var images = []; 
var time = 3000; 
  
images[0] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162514-Just-Breathe.jpg";
images[1] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162513-Be-Someone-s-Sunshine.jpg";
images[2] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162508-Don-t-Cry-.jpg";

var nextbutton=document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click",rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton=document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
prevbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);

function rightbuttonclick(){
   i++;
   changeImg();
}

function leftbuttonclick(){
   i--;
   changeImg();
}

function changeImg(){

   document.getElementById('startersliders').src = images[i];

   if(i < images.length - 1){
      i++; 
   } 

   else { 
      i = 0;
   }

   // Run function every x seconds
   setTimeout("changeImg()", time);

}

function changenext(){
   i++;
   changeImg();
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload=changeImg;
```

```html
<button id="leftbutton">left</button>

<img id="startersliders"  width="400" height="200"/>

<button id="rightbutton">right</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that can help you,

```
 var prevbutton=document.querySelector("#leftbutton");

//nextbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);

prevbutton.addEventListener("click",leftbuttonclick);
```

Comment: @pferadm thats not the issue but yah it was bug in the code thank you for pointing that out i have made the changes but the issue still persist

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable eg: `setTime` that decides whether to call setTimeout again or not.

```
function rightbuttonclick() {
  i++;
  changeImg(false);
}

function leftbuttonclick() {
  i--;
  changeImg(false);
}


function changeImg(setTime) {
  document.getElementById('startersliders').src = images[i];

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  // Run function every x seconds
  if (setTime !== false)
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
```

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3000;


images[0] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162514-Just-Breathe.jpg";
images[1] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162513-Be-Someone-s-Sunshine.jpg";
images[2] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162508-Don-t-Cry-.jpg";

var nextbutton = document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click", rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton = document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
prevbutton.addEventListener("click", leftbuttonclick);

function rightbuttonclick() {
  i++;
  changeImg(false);
}

function leftbuttonclick() {
  i--;
  changeImg(false);
}

function changeImg(setTime) {
  document.getElementById('startersliders').src = images[i];

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  // Run function every x seconds
  if (setTime !== false)
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}


// Run function when page loads
window.onload = changeImg();
```

```html
<button id="leftbutton">left</button>
<img id="startersliders" width="400" height="200" />

<button id="rightbutton">right</button>
```

Or you can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` as shown below:

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3000;


images[0] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162514-Just-Breathe.jpg";
images[1] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162513-Be-Someone-s-Sunshine.jpg";
images[2] = "https://cache.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/162508-Don-t-Cry-.jpg";

var nextbutton = document.querySelector("#rightbutton");
nextbutton.addEventListener("click", rightbuttonclick);

var prevbutton = document.querySelector("#leftbutton");
prevbutton.addEventListener("click", leftbuttonclick);

function rightbuttonclick() {
  i++;
  changeImg(false);
}

function leftbuttonclick() {
  i--;
  changeImg(false);
}

function changeImg(setTime) {
  document.getElementById('startersliders').src = images[i];

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

}
window.onload = changeImg();
setInterval(function() {
  changeImg()
}, time);
```

```html
<button id="leftbutton">left</button>
<img id="startersliders" width="400" height="200" />

<button id="rightbutton">right</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `clearTimeout` function to `chageImg()` and it will work,
as to why it was behaving strangely is because `setTimeout` was been called multiple times. you should always be careful when using `setInverval` or `setTimeout`. here is a code snippet

```
function changeImg(){
  clearTimeout(interval);
    document.getElementById('startersliders').src = images[i];


  if(i < images.length - 1){

      i++; 
    } 
  else { 

        i = 0;
    }

    // Run function every x seconds
    interval = setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
```